# NetSuite SuiteScript 2.0 : Inline HTML document.querySelector() Result

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript

I have a SuiteScript 2.0 **Inline HTML** field that has its default value being injected via a script that successfully fetches a webpage and scrapes desired data (i.e. hack):

```js
@NScriptType UserEventScript

var field = scriptContext.form.addField({
            id: 'custpageinjectcode',
            type: 'INLINEHTML',
            label: 'Inject Code'
});
field.defaultValue = "<script> ...var desiredText = document.querySelector(...).innerText; alert(desiredText);'jQuery(function($){ require(['/SuiteScripts/clientSuiteScript.js'], function(mod){ mod.pageInit();});});'</script>"
```

I also have a clientScript with Listener:

```js
@NScriptType ClientScript

function (currentRecord) {

        function pageInit() {
            window.addEventListener("message", browser_ReceiveMessage, false);
            console.log('Added Listener...');

        }

        return {
            pageInit: pageInit
        }


        function browser_ReceiveMessage(event) {

            var curRec = currentRecord.get();
            console.log('Current Record ID', curRec.id)
        }//end function

    }//end main function

);//end script
```

How would I go about passing this 'desiredText' **result** (i.e. the actual scraped text) back to a normal text variable for use on a NetSuite form, considering the field value is just a string that gets passed to the browser for processing?

Thank you for your time and consideration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) to post data from *inlineHTML* field to a message listener which would be in your **client-script** and this listener would update the said fields data.

Comment: Hello, I've modified my original post, which now includes a clientScript with a Listener. I need additional clarification on how/where to use PostMessage, and how to use the Listener to retrieve the resulting "scraped data" value for variable usage.

Comment: In your inlineHTML field where you set defaultValue, once you have scrapped the data, then you will use _postMessage_. You check [this](https://robertnyman.com/html5/postMessage/postMessage.html) blog out on how to use postMessage.